# I have installed Ubuntu, cannot access Windows 7 and data

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, partitioning

I have a laptop which has Windows 7 on it with 8gb RAM and 1TB hard disk(single C partition). I thought of learning linux and wanted to get Ubuntu. So, I got it into USB and while installing it gave 2 options: 1) Install ubuntu while replacing windows 7 files 2)Some other. I have choosen 2nd option and made a new partition. Ubuntu is installed successfully. When I reboot I dont see windows options and I tried to find windows files from file system in ubuntu, but no luck :( I have treid Boot Repair and here is the url: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6544538/
In boot-repair, the option to repair windows file is not enabled :(. so not able to try that. My concern is about the data. I am fine if I dont have windows. I need to recover that data some how. Please help me.

I am new to ubuntu and terminal. Any help,suggestions are appreciated. Please let me know if more details are needed. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

From the boot-repair log it was clearly shown that you deleted windows partition and installed Ubuntu on it(*that is Ubuntu overwrites windows*).

Try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk),it would recover some datas from the deleted partition.

Comment: It's worth trying TestDisk, but don't get your hopes up; chances are your Windows disk is unrecoverable. You might be able to recover some individual files with [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or some similar software, though. Whatever you do, ***STOP USING THE DISK IMMEDIATELY!!!*** Every moment you use the disk means that you're risking *more* damage to whatever might remain of your Windows installation and user files!